# hide empty collection in / from menu in Shopify

Tags: collections, shopify

I recently moved from Woocommerce to Shopify. I am using Expanse theme from Shopify. I have set listings not to show once they sold out or no stock is available. I need help with hiding the collection from menu that has no stock. I am going to add the code below. Kindly help what code line i need to add within that code.

The header navigation liquid code is below;

```html
{%- liquid
  unless limit
    assign limit = main_menu.links.size
  endunless
  unless offset
    assign offset = 0
  endunless
-%}

<ul class="site-nav site-navigation site-navigation--{{ nav_position }} small--hide" role="navigation">
  {%- for link in main_menu.links limit: limit offset: offset -%}
    {%- liquid
      assign has_dropdown = false
      assign is_megamenu = false
      if link.levels > 0
        assign has_dropdown = true
        if link.levels > 1
          assign is_megamenu = true
        endif
      endif

      assign isCollection = false
      if show_mega_products
        if is_megamenu and link.url contains '/collections/' 
          assign lang_code_string = request.locale.iso_code | prepend: '/' | downcase
          assign collection_handle = link.url | remove: '/collections/' | remove: lang_code_string
          assign collection_drop = collections[collection_handle]
          assign isCollection = true
        endif
      endif
    -%}

    <li
      class="site-nav__item site-nav__expanded-item{% if has_dropdown %} site-nav--has-dropdown{% endif %}{% if is_megamenu %} site-nav--is-megamenu{% endif %}"
      {% if has_dropdown %}aria-haspopup="true"{% endif %}>

      <a href="{{ link.url }}" class="site-nav__link site-nav__link--underline{% if has_dropdown %} site-nav__link--has-dropdown{% endif %}">
        {{ link.title }}
      </a>
      {%- if is_megamenu -%}
        {%- assign previous_column_type = '' -%}
        <div class="site-nav__dropdown megamenu text-left">
          <div class="page-width">
            <div class="site-nav__dropdown-animate megamenu__wrapper">
              <div class="megamenu__cols">
                <div class="megamenu__col">
                  {%- for childlink in link.links -%}
                    {%- liquid
                      assign create_new_column = false

                      if childlink.levels > 0 and forloop.index != 1
                        assign create_new_column = true
                      endif

                      if childlink.levels == 0 and previous_column_type == 'full'
                        assign create_new_column = true
                      endif
                    -%}

                    {%- if create_new_column -%}
                      </div><div class="megamenu__col">
                    {%- endif -%}

                    <div class="megamenu__col-title">
                      <a href="{{ childlink.url }}" class="site-nav__dropdown-link site-nav__dropdown-link--top-level">{{ childlink.title }}</a>
                    </div>

                    {%- liquid
                      if childlink.levels > 0
                        assign previous_column_type = 'full'
                      else
                        assign previous_column_type = 'single'
                      endif
                    -%}

                    {%- for grandchildlink in childlink.links -%}
                      <a href="{{ grandchildlink.url }}" class="site-nav__dropdown-link">
                        {{grandchildlink.title}}
                      </a>
                    {%- endfor -%}
                  {%- endfor -%}
                </div>
              </div>
              {%- if isCollection -%}
                <div class="megamenu__featured">
                  <div class="product-grid">
                    {%- liquid
                      assign mega_product = collection_drop.products.first
                      render 'product-grid-item', product: mega_product
                      if settings.quick_shop_enable
                        render 'quick-shop-modal', product: mega_product
                      endif
                    -%}
                  </div>
                </div>
              {%- endif -%}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      {%- elsif has_dropdown -%}
        <div class="site-nav__dropdown">
          <ul class="site-nav__dropdown-animate site-nav__dropdown-list text-left">
            {%- for childlink in link.links -%}
              {%- liquid
                assign has_sub_dropdown = false
                if childlink.levels > 0
                  assign has_sub_dropdown = true
                endif
              -%}

              <li class="{% if has_sub_dropdown %} site-nav__deep-dropdown-trigger{% endif %}">
                <a href="{{ childlink.url }}" class="site-nav__dropdown-link site-nav__dropdown-link--second-level{% if has_sub_dropdown %} site-nav__dropdown-link--has-children{% endif %}">
                  {{ childlink.title | escape }}
                  {%- if has_sub_dropdown -%}
                    <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" role="presentation" class="icon icon--wide icon-chevron-down" viewBox="0 0 28 16"><path d="M1.57 1.59l12.76 12.77L27.1 1.59" stroke-width="2" stroke="#000" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"/></svg>
                  {%- endif -%}
                </a>
                {%- if has_sub_dropdown -%}
                  <ul class="site-nav__deep-dropdown">
                    {%- for grandchildlink in childlink.links -%}
                      <li>
                        <a href="{{ grandchildlink.url }}" class="site-nav__dropdown-link">{{ grandchildlink.title | escape }}</a>
                      </li>
                    {%- endfor -%}
                  </ul>
                {%- endif -%}
              </li>
            {%- endfor -%}
          </ul>
        </div>
      {%- endif -%}
    </li>
  {%- endfor -%}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to check if a link object is a collection and if it contains or not available products (which I understand is your question) (not tested):

```
{% if link.type == 'collection_link' %}
    {% assign c_products = link.object.products | where: "available" %}
    {% if c_products.size > 0 %}
        Display the link
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Explanations:

First, I check if the current link is a link to a collection by checking type value.

If it is, I define an array of available products contained by the collection (accessing it via link.object) whith a filter. The where filter is here to keep only available products in the array.

Then I check if the array size, then I know whether collection contains available products or not.

HTH

Useful documentation :

- Link object: https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects#link
- Where filter (arrays): https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/where/
- Size filter (arrays): https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/size/

Comment: Thanks, Where should i enter this code in order to check if it working perfectly please?

Comment: Code seems to be fine but how to hide an empty collection? It's showing "Display the link" instead of hiding the collections from dropdown menu.